# onbefore unload in Firefox

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events, onbeforeunload

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var sessionID = getQuerystring('SessionID');
        var cookieSessionID = getCookie('session');
        var validNavigation = false;

        function endSession() {
            setCookie('session', sessionID, 1);
            var cookieSU = getCookie('session');
            if (cookieSU != null) {
                getSyncData('strSessionId=' + sessionID, 'UpdateUserLogoutSession');
            }
        }

        function wireUpEvents() {
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                if (!validNavigation) {
                    endSession();
                }
            }


            $('document').bind('keypress', function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 116) {
                    validNavigation = true;
                }
            });

            $("a").bind("click", function () {
                validNavigation = true;
            });

            $("form").bind("submit", function () {
                validNavigation = true;
            });

            $("input[type=submit]").bind("click", function () {
                validNavigation = true;
            });

        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (cookieSessionID == null || cookieSessionID != sessionID) {
                // Do nothing
            } else {
                if (cookieSessionID == sessionID) {
                    getData('strSessionId=' + sessionID, 'UpdateUserResetSession', function (result) {
                        if (result['Exception']) { };
                    });
                }
            }
            wireUpEvents();
        });

        function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }
        function getCookie(c_name) {
            var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
            for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
                x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
                y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
                x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
                if (x == c_name) {
                    return unescape(y);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Here I am calling

```
UpdateUserLogoutSession
```

in

```
window.onbeforeunload
```

event...

Now the problem is this works great on IE and Chrome..but it doesn't work on Firefox browser...

This function identify whether the page is REFRESHED or Closed........
So I want to use

```
UpdateUserResetSession
```

on Refresh event and

```
UpdateUserLogoutSession
```

on close..!

Is there a way to do this in Firefox?
And Why it is not working?
One more thing.... if I put

```
alert("hi");
```

after

```
setCookie('session', sessionID, 1);
            var cookieSU = getCookie('session');
            if (cookieSU != null) {
                getSyncData('strSessionId=' + sessionID, 'UpdateUserLogoutSession');
            }
```

it just works great.. but when I try without alert.. it doesn't work?

What's the problem?

Comment: Did you try adding a "return 'example' ; " instead of a alert? does it do the same thing in regards to it working with an alert or not at all?

Comment: i got this same issue, only it doesn't work for me if i add an alert either

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and this is what finally worked for me (using jQuery):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){

});
```